# Java: Bytes are not transferred correctly

Tags: java, java-io

I've made a server that should let the client udpate a file. All in all it is working, but some bytes, for example HEX 9D is getting to HEX 3F. I have no more ideas and didn't find anything on the web. My server code:

```
package de;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class UpdateThread extends Thread {
public UpdateThread(Socket s) {
    socket = s;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void execute() throws IOException {
    if (UpdateProvider.update) {
        int i = 0;
        SocketTools.sendData(1, socket);
        File file = new File("." + System.getProperty("file.separator").toString()     + "update_package.jar");
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new   OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        while ((i = reader.read()) != -1) {
            writer.write(i);
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } else {
        SocketTools.sendData(0, socket);
    }
}

private Socket socket;

}
```

And my client code:

```
package de;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 16642);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    //InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
    int i = 0;
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\update_package.jar"));

    int state = reader.read();

    if (state == 48) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (state == 49) {
        while ((i = reader.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(i);
            writer.write(i);
        }
        System.out.println("ENDE");
        writer.flush();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Classes that end in "Writer" are meant for characters. Not for bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying a proper encoding for the transmission (you should use `InputStream`/`OutputStreams` instead of `Reader`/`Writer` for this anyways, since you're handling binary data and not text). 0x3F is the questionmark '?', meaning that a non-ASCII character (128 or higher) has been converted.

So lose the Readers and Writers and go with Streams.

Comment: Ok, I've replaced the `FileReader` with `FileInputStream` and `FileWriter` with `FileOutputStream`, but it's still not working. There are still much qestion marks! (3f)

Comment: Then it sounds that somewhere you're still converting bytes to characters. What's your updated code?

Comment: Ok it was too long for a comment and I can't still anser my own qestion :/ So here it is: http://www.mediafire.com/view/q7ui91o2n30noju/Code.txt

Comment: @Ercksen: if what you want to transfer is not text (or its text, but you don't care about that), then you **must** get rid of **all** `Writer` and `Reader` in there. You still use them for the socket communication, so while you now read correctly from the file, your *socket* code still tries to handle text.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding is needed for text files only. I looked at your source code. You are trasferring a jar, which is a **binary** file, not text. If you use use text processing classes for binary data, you can get a lot of unpredictable transformations. Don't use OutputStreamWriter. Use socket.getOutputStream() directly:

```
OutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
...
out.write(...);
```

Same for client. Don't use InputStreamReader. Use s.getInputStream() directly:

```
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
...
in.read(...);
```